# Less Extend (как правильно наследовать ?)

Tags: less

как правильно наследовать след. элементы:

```
 .b-mod{
    &__portfolio{
       position: relative;
       padding: 52px 0px 0px;
       text-align: center;
       overflow: hidden;

    .modulePretext{
      font-size: 16px;
      margin-bottom: 67px;
    }
  }

  &__about{

    /* наследовать стили от .b-mod__portfolio */

    .modulePretext{
      /* наследовать стили от .b-mod__portfolio .modulePretext */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так пробовали?

```
&__about{
  &:extend(.b-mod__portfolio);

  .modulePretext{
    &:extend(.b-mod__portfolio .modulePretext);
  }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает

Comment: &__about:extend(.b-mod__portfolio){} - так тоже не работает